# Semantical Error line 0, col 63 near g, product p: Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Product has no association symfony2 application

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to access the great grand children of entities in one-to-many relationship. For example: Department entity(parent) -> Category entity(children)->Group entity(grand children)->Product entity(great grandchildren). I want to fetch products based on their department.

**Department relationship with category:**

```
/**
 *  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="department")
 */
protected $category;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->category = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

**Category relationship with department and group:**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Department", inversedBy="category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="department_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $department;
/**
 *  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Group", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $group;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->group = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

**Group relationship with Category and Product:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="group")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;

/**
 *  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="group")
 */
protected $product;
public function  construct()
{
    $this->product = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Brand", inversedBy="group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="brand_groups")
 */
private $brand;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->brand = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

**Product relationship with Group:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="groups_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $group;
```

**ProductRepository:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;

/**
 * ProductRepository
 */
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findDepartmentProduct($department)
    {
        return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select(array('p', 'g','c','d'))
            ->from('Product', 'p')
            ->join('p.Group', 'g')
            ->join('g.Category', 'c')
            ->join('c.Department', 'd')
            ->where('d = :department')
            ->setParameter('department', $department)
            ->getQuery();
    }
}
```

**DefaultController:**

```
/**
 * @Route("/department/{id}", name = "department")
 */
public function departmentAction(Request $request,$id)
{
    $Department = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Department');
    $department = $Department->find($id);

    $Product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
    $customersChoiceProducts = $Product->mostView('20');

    $query = $query = $Product->findDepartmentProduct($department);

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query, 
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
        8/*limit per page*/
    );

    return $this->render('default/department.html.twig', array(
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'department' => $department,
        'customersChoiceProducts' => $customersChoiceProducts,
    ));
}
```

Then I get this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 63 near 'g, product p': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Product has no association named groups

Please help me.

Comment: You are joining the association, not the entity class names, so you should have `->join('p.group', 'g')` instead of `->join('p.Group', 'g')`

Comment: thank you @Jason am using knp paginator now i get this error Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction . ->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p')
            ->from('AppBundle:Product','l')
            ->join('p.group', 'g')
            ->join('g.category', 'c')
            ->join('c.department', 'd')
            ->where('d = :department')
            ->setParameter('department', $department)
            ->getQuery();

Comment: Try `->createQueryBuilder('p')->join('p.group', 'g') ->join('g.category', 'c') ->join('c.department', 'd') ->where('d = :department') ->setParameter('department', $department) ->getQuery(); `

Comment: thank you man i fixed it by adding the ->getResult(). so instead of passing query to knp paginator i passed result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I made was joining the entity class name instead of the association. My new code is:

```
public function findDepartmentProduct($department)
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->select('p')
        ->from('AppBundle:Product','p')
        ->join('p.group', 'g')
        ->join('g.category', 'c')
        ->join('c.department', 'd')
        ->where('d = :department')
        ->setParameter('department', $department)
        ->getQuery();
}
```

If you run this you would get the following error:

> Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction

You solve this error by adding `->getResult()`

```
public function findDepartmentProduct($department)
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->select('p')
        ->from('AppBundle:Product','p')
        ->join('p.group', 'g')
        ->join('g.category', 'c')
        ->join('c.department', 'd')
        ->where('d = :department')
        ->setParameter('department', $department)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```